# Redis concurrent Read and Update

Tags: c#, .net, redis

Supposedly I have json serialized object with a count property stored as a value . If two users retrieve the object at the same time and update the count with + 1 when they save it back the count value will be corrupted.

What is the correct way to handle this scenario with Redis? I am using Stackexchange client for .Net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need transactions to guarantee consistency. In redis it can be done with [multi](https://redis.io/commands/multi) command.

With Stackexchange, it can be done like this (example adapted from their [doc](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Transactions))

```
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
// Using transaction will lock "mykey" entry, so that all operation on this key are consistent. 
// All other clients attempting to manipulate this key, will have to wait for the end of transaction.
var tran = db.CreateTransaction(); 
string json = tran.StringGet("mykey");
// here, you should deserialize json, increment count value and serialize it back to string
string updated = handle_value(json);
tran.StringSet("mykey");
tran.Execute();
```

Note that serializing and deserializing json can be expensive and you can gains some performance by using a [hash](https://redis.io/commands#hash) instead.

Edit: Fix example and some explanations.

Comment: The doc also state: "....Redis will automatically keep track of this key, and any changes will essentially doom our transaction to rollback ... "

My aim is for both operations to succeed and update count to a correct value.

Comment: Thank your updated answer. I have a little more complicated scenario - the object has a property which is collection of child objects. That is the reason I was looking into json serialization.

I am aware of performance issues but it is hard to break it down into HashSets and Lists